# Bezier Curve Length

Tags: point, curve

How can I calculated the length of a bezier curve programmatically? given 4 points; the ends of the curve and the two control points. Can someone help me with the algorithm please?

Comment: where are you stuck in the algorithm?

Comment: @Woot4Moo I'd like to implement this algorithm http://algorithmist.wordpress.com/2009/01/05/quadratic-bezier-arc-length/ 
source code: http://www.algorithmist.net/bezierarclength/srcview/index.html but I don't know how to access the points on the path i.e. bezierPath.pointAt(t)

Answer (score 2):

If you know your calculus, you could take the parametric form of the bezier curve off Wikipedia or something and use this:

http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/ParaArcLength.aspx

to calculate its length. I assume that you tried to google for this before asking, and found out that nobody had posted the solution already.

If you're not into calculus, you can get a reasonable approximation by approximating the curve with a polyline, whose length is easy to calculate.

Comment: I'm not good at calculus. I searched and found many ways to calculate the length of a quadratic bezier curve (4 control points) but didn't know which one to use. I'd like to implement this http://algorithmist.wordpress.com/2009/01/05/quadratic-bezier-arc-length/ source code: http://www.algorithmist.net/bezierarclength/srcview/index.html but I don't know how to access the points on the path i.e. bezierPath.pointAt(t).

Comment: @B.A If whatever library you're using doesn't have support for getting the points on the path, you can always calculate them yourself. The equations are all available at Wikipedia and involve no math higher than high-school level.

Answer (score 0):

Bézier curve is sum(pi bi,k(u)). You can sample the curve by increment ing the u with very small numbers and calculate the distance between two consecutive points on the curve and add them up. This is the calculation of poly line length that matti also mentioned.